# Normal Map incorrect

Tags: normal-map

I don't understand why when I bake the nornal map for a body i cannot see the colors anymore on the normal map.[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, sorry i couldn't answear, i solved the problem just by making a new file and copying everything there and it worked.